# Can't add custom object to Navigation Menu in Community

Tags: community, lightning

I've been using Community Builder for quite a while now and have had no problems.

I recently went to add another tab to my navigation menu (to point to a "Salesforce Object" page and was surprised to find that I was unable to add one of my custom objects.  I have been able to do this with multiple custom objects before.  For some reason this custom object (Issue) is not on the list of available objects.

[image: Adding object tab to Navigation Menu]

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Upon further investigation I found that indeed other custom objects don't appear in the list as well.  Only certain custom objects are there while others are missing.  I tried finding a common thread (relationship, created date, etc.) to no avail.

Comment: there is a limit of 10custom objects per community user licence. has you already added 10 custom objects?

Comment: I'm not sure.  How do you add or remove objects to a community / license.
I checked in Object Settings for one of our Partner Community licenses and it seems there is way more than 10 there with either Read or Edit access.

Comment: Remember that Managed Package objects do not count towards the 10 object limit, so that may explain some of the objects in the list. It may be obvious but have you checked the profiles have permission to see the objects, not only community users but also System Administrators?

Comment: Yes, we access these objects regularly from within Salesforce.  Also it seems to me that permissions would affect the way people view and interact with objects in the published community, not within the builder.

Comment: So the answer was Custom Tabs.  Apparently the object has to have a custom object tab created in order for it to appear as an option in Community Builder.

Comment: @SaarKagan please add the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

for a tab to show in the list it needs to be default on for all profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The 'default on' tab visibility for all profiles with access to the experience cloud site resolved my issue of the object not being available within the edit navigation, salesforce object screen.